# How to turn a matrix into a dictionary suitable for selectinput choices

Tags: r, shiny

```
        name         id                                  
 [1,] "Test1" "54754756576OE7VGV3"

 [2,] "Test2" "43656OYY2AF22452DL"

 [3,] "Test3" "0144676KXHKFF33MF3"

 [4,] "Test4" "0112424PRAJPSWQGZT"

 [5,] "Test5" "015465PWIDOKQBPHY"
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how can I turn such a dataframe into a list suitable for the choices of a selectInput?

e.g.

```
list(Test1 = 54754756576OE7VGV3, Test2 = 43656OYY2AF22452DL, ...)
```

Comment: What you have is a matrix. Use `setNames(as.list(m[,2]), m[,1])` where m is your variable

Comment: If you had an actual data.frame `tibble::deframe()` would work well

Comment: Thank you @Ric Villalba! I have changed the title of the question to reflect that it is a matrix. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.